# Editing layout xml attributes not displaying changes, but able to by getting reference to the view objects and calling its layout changing methods

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Essentially I can't get the View's layout attributes to register on the UI unless I programmatically call, for instance, textViewInstance.setTextColor(rainbow). Any ideas as to why?

Edit: I meant that the following code works:

messageTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.headline));

BUT doing the following in the view's layout xml does NOT:

```
   @+id/messageTextView
   ...
   textColor="@color/headline"
```

Comment: rainbow is code for color ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This method...

```
 tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#C10000"));
```

OR

```
String rainbow = "#C10000";
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(rainbow));
```